# Verify more than one word with the expected result in Robotium Script

Tags: java, android, automation, robotium

I need a help regarding robotium scripts. My scenario is like 3 same word are there in my AUT.I need to verify whether all the three words are correct or not with the expected result.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of these methods:

```
boolean searchText(String text, int minimumNumberOfMatches)
Searches for the specified text and returns true if the searched text is found a specified number of times.
boolean searchText(String text, int minimumNumberOfMatches, boolean scroll)
Searches for the specified text and returns true if the searched text is found a specified number of times.
boolean searchText(String text, int minimumNumberOfMatches, boolean scroll, boolean onlyVisible)
Searches for the specified text and returns true if the searched text is found a specified number of times.
```

If the question is different attach a screenshot of what you want to test.

Comment: Could you accept this answer as solution to the question?